# Developing a game using opengl

Tags: opengl

Hello Everyone, 
               I want to create a game using OPEN GL to learn basics of the game development. I know C++ and OOPS and can manage the coding. I have tried using the free engines on the market like Unreal Engine, Unity and Game Maker. Unreal Engine in particular doesn't work well on my System due to it's higher requirements. Even all other engines have some kind of abstraction to themselves. I have time to spare. So, please suggest me a starting point to start developing using OPEN GL and also the math required to create them. All I want to do is learn it thoroughly at the lower level.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "How to get started" questions are unfortunately not a good fit for this site, see the FAQ. As such, this question will likely be closed. I suggest you go to the gamedev.net forums for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same boat a couple of years ago. All engines will have some abstractions that are strange and take some getting used to. Building your own engine will cause a lot of heartache and difficulties you did not expect down the road. I had to move my engine over to Box2D just to handle the massive undertaking physics had on my project.

If you're sincerely in the mood to build the engine, it doesn't take much to get started, but it takes a lot to get through the learning phase (your first couple of games).

My only input would be to not do everything yourself. OpenGL is awesome, but look for other libraries which will suit your needs in the long run.

In terms of resources for OpenGL; [LearnOpenGL](http://learnopengl.com/), compared to any other resources, this website is by far the best I've come across, It even has a section on how to build a 2D game right at the end. I tried studying [The Red Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321773039), but this is far too low level for a new comer to the API.

Goodluck!

Comment: Thank you, I have been following the site for sometime. :D. And, what are the other Libraries?. Are you talking about Direct3d or more higher level libraries like OGRE 3d and Irrilicht.

Comment: @user3869190 The site is a wonder! I use Box2D for physics, some other libraries for I/O of files (XML, TOML). I haven't worked much in Direct3d, but I use SDL for input and opengl management. The more I work, the more libraries end up following me for the ride. ImGUI will come in pretty soon.

Answer (score 0):

I would STRONGLY RECOMMEND you to follow this YouTube tutorial series:

[3D Game Engine Development Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEETnX-uPtBXP_B2yupUKlflXBznWIlL5)

It is a good starting point to learn the basics and although the tutorial is based on Java, you should be able to recreate it in any languages you prefer. (:

Comment: Thank you for the input. I know little bit of java. So, no problem to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

The official OpenGL documentation is well done, but IMHO you need a background of how a game is structured, what is and how a shader works and - first of all - how the **rendering pipeline** works. If you have time (and money), [Real-Time Rendering](http://www.realtimerendering.com/) gives you the theory you need.

Anyway, from my experience I understood that the best way to learn how to write a game is to study someone else code. I suggest you [THIS](https://code.google.com/p/demo-glsl/): *Real Time 3D Demo* written in C++ and GLSL. Of course, on the web there are a lot of alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and pointing the resources. I am checking them right now. :)